# Keep Time Value after closing the browser and calls it again - Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, timer, counter

I asked yesterday about saving a timer value when the browser closes and then start counting again when the user opens it. I've found that using cookies must be a good solution, so i've added the set and getcookie functions, but still i can't get my timer values. This might be easy, but i cant see what's wrong because i'm still too noob in javascript.
Does someone know what i'm doing wrong?
thank you!!
here's the code i have so far:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"><head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
var sec = 0;
var min =  0;
var hr = 0;
var dias = 0;
var bool = true;
function stopwatch() {
        sec++;
        if (sec == 60) {
            sec = 0;
            min += 1;
        }

        if (min == 60) {
            min = 0;
            hr += 1;
        }

        if (hr == 24) {
            hr = 0;
            dias += 1;
        }

        totalTime = ((dias<=9) ? "0" + dias : dias) + "d, " + ((hr<=9) ? "0" + hr : hr) + " : " + ((min<=9) ? "0" + min : min) + " : " + ((sec<=9) ? "0" + sec : sec);
        document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = totalTime;
        if (bool == true) {
        start = setTimeout("stopwatch()", 1000);

        }
    }

function setCookie(name, value, expires) {
document.cookie = name + "=" + escape(value) + "; path=/" + ((expires == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + expires.toGMTString());
}



function getCookie (name) {
    var cname = name + "=";               
    var dc = document.cookie;

    if (dc.length > 0) {              
        begin = dc.indexOf(cname);       
            if (begin != -1) {           
            begin += cname.length;       
            end = dc.indexOf(";", begin);
                if (end == -1) end = dc.length;
                return unescape(dc.substring(begin, end));
            } 
        }
    return null;
}


var exp = new Date();                                  
exp.setTime(exp.getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30));

    </script>
</head>
<body onload="stopwatch()">
    <div id="timer" name="timer"> </div>
  <button onclick="bool = false"; > pause </button>
  <button onclick="bool = true;stopwatch();" > resume </button>

    <form>
      <input type="button" value="Set a Cookie" onClick="setCookie('myCookie',timer.value, exp)">
    </form>
<form>
<input type="button" value="Get Cookie Value" onClick="this.form.tf.value = getCookie('myCookie')">
<input type="text" name="tf" size="30">
</form>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm confused regarding your "java" tag -- How does this involve Java? It looks to be all JavaScript. You do understand that they are as different as night and day, right?

Comment: Don't use strings in `setTimeout`.

Comment: Initialise your variables as numbers, not strings.

Comment: **Never** pass a string to `setInterval()` or `setTimeout()`. Doing so is as bad as using `eval()` and it results in unreadable and possibly insecure code as soon as you use variables since you need to insert them into the string instead of passing the actual variable. The proper solution is `setInterval(function() { /* your code *) }, msecs);`. The same applies to `setTimeout()`. If you just want to call a single function without any arguments, you can also pass the function name directly: `setInterval(someFunction, msecs);` (note that there are **no** `()` behind the function name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, few issues with your code:

- Strings shouldn't be used in `setTimeout`s
- Your variables should be initialised as integers, not strings.

---

Back to your problem, use the unload event to save a cookie with the current time when the user closes the page. Then when the user opens the page again, detect the cookie and continue from where you left off.

Comment: Edit your original answer if you want to add additional info.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't figure out how to pause it, what about getting the Date when the browser closes and then getting the date when it opens again.  Calculate the difference and subtract it from the value your timer is at.

I'm just throwing a general idea out there! :D